# Не получается сделать css Отступ для opera

Tags: css, webkit, opera

В хроме:

```
#nav_top {
    max-height:25px;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 207px; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

В опере, как не пытался, ничего не работает, если в f12 в опера меняю на нужный `top:232px;`, то Хром страдает, ему надо 207px.

Comment: *{padding:0; margin: 0;} - может, это поможет?

Comment: а какая версия оперы? Если уж очень нужно, то можно определить браузер через JS и там поставить ему `top` для нужного браузера

Comment: Тогда уже лучше css hack для оперы взять. 
http://www.web-utils.net/css-hack/browser-list-ie-firefox-opera-safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 max-height:25px;
```

Может быть, попробовать просто height дописать?

Вообще без реального примера сложно что-то сказать...

Как пальцем в небо получается.

Comment: согласен, без примера нормально не решить, прочитал внимательнее, думаю, проблема в css, а не в работе браузера

Answer (score 0):

в Opera нужно line-height прописывать.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?